# Handling relative urls in a Node.js http server

Tags: node.js, http

I'm currently using a small server created using the http module of Node.js, and I have a small issue with relative urls. Since Node.js and web related things are not my specialty, I don't know how to fix it.

The problem is the following: I have a small index.html page that loads a font via `@font-face` and `url("some_relative_path")`. Then if in my browser I enter this url `http://localhost:8000/test/` then my server finds the `index.html` file, and correctly loads the font.

But then if I enter this one `http://localhost:8000/test` (notice the / at the end that is now missing) I see my `index.html`, but the font is not loaded.

Here is the (I think) relevent parts of my server code:

```
(function main() {

    var http        = require("http"),
        url         = require("url"),
        path        = require("path"),
        fs          = require("fs");

    // start the server
    http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        console.log(request.url);

        // compute the file name
        var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), url.parse(request.url).pathname);

        // check if the url points to a folder, in which case, try to locate an index.html file
        if (fs.existsSync(filename) && fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
            filename = path.join(filename, "index.html");
        }

        // check if the file exists
        fs.exists(filename, function (exists) {
            if (!exists) {
                // return 404 error if not found
                response.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
                response.end("404 Not Found\n");
            } else {
                // write the response
                response.writeHead(200, { });
                fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
            }
        });

    }).listen(parseInt(8000, 10));
})();
```

Now, the url of the font is `url("./resources/font.ttf")`. When I browse to `http://localhost:8000/test/` the request's url for the font is `test/resources/font.ttf`, and it works fine.

But when I omit the trailing slash, then the request's url for the font becomes `resources/font.ttf`, thus the error.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe a malformed response ? The way I compute the filename ? Any help appreciated :)

Edit: As the accepted answer pointed out, I need to redirect urls that point to a folder but do not have a trailing slash. Here is the piece of code that does it, for reference:

```
// check if we are requested a folder
if (fs.existsSync(filename) && fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
    // if the url doesn't end with a slash, we need to redirect
    if (request.url.charAt(request.url.length - 1) !== '/') {
        response.writeHead(302, { "Location": request.url + "/" });
        response.end();
        return;
    } else {
        // try to locate an index.html
        filename = path.join(filename, "index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the browser deciding what the request should look like when using a relative path. To the browser, the url `http://localhost:8000/test` is basically a file named `test` in the `/` directory. So `./` is now relative to `/`. Similarly, the url `http://localhost:8000/test/` is looking for the index file in the `/test/` directory. So `./` is relative to `/test/`.

How to fix this: If the request is a file but the request has no trailing slash, then respond with a redirect to the URL with a trailing slash.

This might be how I would do it:

```
if (fs.existsSync(filename) && fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
    if (filename.indexOf('/', filename.length - 1) == -1) {
        //No trailing slash.
        //TODO: redirect to url with a trailing slash
        return;
    }

    filename = path.join(filename, "index.html");
}
```

Comment: It was indeed the redirection that I was missing (I didn't even know that I had to handle this :)) Thanks !